# laravel scope model function error

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to sum amount up all cash_sales_items that belong to particular cash_sale using scope in laravel. The problem is when i have some information in those tables the code works fine but when the tables are empty i get an error

```
Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string
```

below is the code and table structures

```
accessories_cash_salesmysql> describe accessories_cash_sales;
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| client        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| exchange_rate | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| employee_id   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| status        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| tax           | varchar(255)     | NO   |     |         |                |
| created_at    | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at    | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and the other is

```
mysql> describe accessories_cash_sales_items;
+--------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| accessories_id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| quantity                 | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| amount                   | int(11)          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| accessories_cash_sale_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_at               | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at               | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Am calling the scope method in the blade template with

```
\App\AccessoriesCashSale::paidOrCollected()
```

and in the cash sale model paidOrCollected function looks like

```
public function scopePaidOrCollected($query){
    $amount = 0;
    $items = $query->where('status', '=', 'paid')->orWhere('status', '=', 'Collected')->whereMonth('created_at','=', date('m'))->get();

    foreach($items as $item){
        $amount = $amount + $item->accessoriesCashSalesItems()->sum('amount');;
    }

    return $amount;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always return the modified query object when using scopes.

```
public function scopePaidOrCollected($query){
    return $query->where('status', '=', 'paid')->orWhere('status', '=', 'Collected')->whereMonth('created_at','=', date('m'));
}
```

Use your scope to filter down your query results, then pass it into another method outside of the scope to iterate over your collection and work out your amounts.

EDIT

You can simply add another method to your model that deals with your scoped data, something like this:

```
public function getCashSaleAmounts()
{
    $items = AccessoriesCashSale::paidOrCollected()->get();
    $amount = 0;

    foreach($items as $item){
        $amount += $item->accessoriesCashSalesItems()->sum('amount');
    }

    return $amount;
}
```

You may want to check your results before trying to loop over them however.

Comment: But that would mean that i have to place the foreach loop in the view. the problem is am trying to create like a dashboard, and my plan was to implement all the functions in the model and only return values instead of placing too much code in the view

Comment: @williamjingo Scopes are for applying a scope to a query object and passing the object back, you're returning your query results INSIDE the scope, iterating over them and returning something completely different. You don't need to call the loop from inside the view, you could add another method to your model which calls the scoped results, loops over them and returns your amounts.